# Calculating twists/turns of vector line using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I currently have a large layer (trails) and want to calculate for each trail how much the trail turns or is distorted between the start and end of the trail.

Is this possible on QGIS 3.6.2?

Comment: These are animal trails mapped out by me using drone data

Comment: I would like to do them automatically as there are thousands

Comment: This sounds like you are after a metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics) to assess how much it turns or disortes, You need to define the metric, it is certailnly possible to implement any once it is well defined.

Comment: Please add your comments into the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the **sinuosity** of the paths. It's a pretty straightforward calculation:

`Start-to-End Straight Line Length / Total Path Length`.

The best part is, we can do it in Q with the **Field Calculator**. 
If I have a layer of paths, everything I need will be in the derived attributes:

[image]

Open up the **Field Calculator**. You'll find everything you need in the **Geometry** section. Here's the expression:

```
length( make_line(
    start_point($geometry),
    end_point($geometry))) /
length($geometry)
```

In the output field, we now have a way of saying how sinuous each path is overall, with 1 being absolutely straight, and near-0 being almost circular.

[image: calculated sinuosity]